# subset list by dataframe names r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

Given a masterlist `A` containing several `dataframes` of data, with names of `A`stored in `Anames`. I need a subset from `Anames` which I store in `Cnames` using `setdiff`function.

Given `A`, how can I use `Cnames` to subset `A`, store it in list `B` and then write each dataframe in `B` to file as shown below? `Anames` and `Cnames` are column vectors.

```
sapply(names(B),function (x)  write.csv(B[[x]],file = paste0(names(B[x]), ".csv"),row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Why do you need `setdiff`?

Comment: `setdiff` finds those names in `Anames` which are also available in my subset of names. The result is stored in `Cnames`

Comment: If it is to find the common elements, use `intersect`.  From your description, it is not very clear.

Comment: @akrun         how to subset `A` using the output of `intersect`?

Comment: `B <- A[intersect(Anames, Cnames)]; lapply(names(B), function(x) write.csv(B[[x]],... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use `intersect` to find the common elements between 'Anames' and 'Cnames'

```
B <- A[intersect(Anames, Cnames)
lapply(names(B), function(x) write.csv(B[[x]], 
        paste0(names(B[x]), ".csv"),row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE))
```